# firebase 5 package is giving error with its own Observer

Tags: firebase, angular6

I was trying to migrate from Angular 5 to Angular 6.. then as we all know.. everything else depend on every other package.. I finally needed to update the firebase package with :

```
npm install -s firebase@latest
```

Then here is the error when I run `ng serve`

> ERROR in node_modules/@firebase/app-types/private.d.ts(130,28): error TS2314: Generic type 'Observer' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> node_modules/@firebase/app-types/private.d.ts(131,34): error TS2314:
>   Generic type 'Observer' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> node_modules/@firebase/auth-types/index.d.ts(271,21): error TS2314:
>   Generic type 'Observer' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> node_modules/@firebase/auth-types/index.d.ts(276,21): error TS2314:
>   Generic type 'Observer' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> node_modules/@firebase/messaging-types/index.d.ts(31,35): error
>   TS2314: Generic type 'Observer' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> node_modules/@firebase/messaging-types/index.d.ts(36,35): error
>   TS2314: Generic type 'Observer' requires 2 type argument(s).
>
> node_modules/@firebase/storage-types/index.d.ts(80,9): error TS2314:
>   Generic type 'Observer' requires 2 type argument(s).

Here is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "test",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "0.0.29",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^0.6.0",
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^6.0.3",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@firebase/app": "^0.3.2",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.1.2",
    "@schematics/package-update": "^0.6.0",
    "ajv": "^6.0.0",
    "angular2-recaptcha": "^0.6.0",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.9",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.5",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.10.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.2",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng2-validation": "^4.2.0",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.1.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.106",
    "codelyzer": "^4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "^2.7.2",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.3"
}
}
```

This is what we can see into the file **node_module/@firebase/app-types/private.d.ts(130,28)**:

```
 /**
 * Create a Subscribe function.  A proxy Observer is created so that
 * events can be sent to single Observer to be fanned out automatically.
 */
createSubscribe<T>(
  executor: (observer: Observer<T>) => void,
  onNoObservers?: (observer: Observer<T>) => void
): Subscribe<T>;
```

How can I make it works without downgrading my Firebase package ?

Comment: Same issue here after updating to the @latest. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Updating to 5.0.3 solved the issue for me.

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis I am already at firebase 5.0.3 and it still have the same issue. I also deleted the package and try to install it with "yarn" instead of npm.. it didn't work either.

Comment: The only thing I can suggest it to try and update angular cli to 6.0.3. I am on the following: "@angular/animations": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/material": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.2",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.2",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.9",
    "firebase": "^5.0.3"
[SOME OMITTED]

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis is your solution working at your place? I tried but still the same issue with firebase 5.0.3

Comment: my solution is working as expected now. Try removing /node_modules and running `npm i`

Comment: @PaulStrupeikis may you share you all package.json ? 

I did what you said but I still get the same issue. I passed 8 hours to fix this without any result.

Comment: npm i @firebase/util solved the issue for me

Comment: Any idea why installing `@firebase/util` would have solved the issue?

Comment: `npm i @firebase/util` also resolved this for me.  Thanks @user1005016

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update typescript, `npm install typescript@2.3 --save` will fix the error.